# Fetch different multiple attributes of same xml tags in xml file separately using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

```
function get_attributes(xml,name_Tag,sParent){    

attribute_Array = new Array();    
$(xml).find(node).each(function(){    

    $.each(this.attributes,function(i,eeeee){
    var namex = eeeee.name;
    var valuex = eeeee.value;
    attribute_Array.push({'attrib_name':namex,'attrib_val':valuex});
    });
});
return attribute_Array;}
```

This code gives me attributes of tag which i have sent as a parameter to function but it gives all the combined attributes if xml has same tag multiple time.
consider following xml:

```
<xml>
<form id="id1" name="form1"></form>
<form id="id2" name="form2"></form>
</xml>
```

When I want to fetch attributes of first form (id="id1",name="form1") this function returns me (id="id1" name="form1" id="id2" name="form2")

Comment: nope its not always first tag....it gives attributes of all same tags combinely.I need the function which supposed to the tag dynamically and fetch attributes according to it

Comment: Then how would the function supposed to know which tag you want based on only the `name_tag`???

Comment: I am facing same problem and need a solution for same.I need to make it dynamic so only i get is the name_tag.